# Ruby Show Key Pressed In Other Programs

Tags: ruby, stdin

In Ruby, I am trying to do something like showing the keypressed while in any program. In the end, I would like to run the program in terminal and store the keys pressed from every program.

The test case would be to run the program in terminal and then go to goole and search for a bit. Then check the program logs and see the keyboard input.

I have tried to use STDIN.read but it seems to not be doing what I want.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: STDIN will only provide access to the lines entered into the terminal during the program's execution. Gaining access to arbitrary keypresses is not possible in Ruby and is hard to implement in user-space programs. You are hampered by the OS due to the security implications of global key-logging.

Comment: I was afraid of that.

Comment: that's a feature of something you know as a root-kit.

Comment: There are plenty of legitimate reasons to do this (like replacement/macro/hotkey tools). ;)